# Using Vue.js to loop through with v-for adding 1 each time inline

Tags: javascript, loops, vue.js, vuejs2

I am looking to loop through `questions.questions` each time adding on like you would but I guess I need to do this inline as I think wish to use the number created to update `item` as the key in the second loop.

```
      <div v-for="question in questions.questions">
        {{question.question}}
        <div v-if="grouped_answers">
          <div v-for="a in grouped_answers[item].answers">
            {{a.id}}
          </div>
        </div>
        {{item += 1}}
      </div>
```

`item` is already set in the data as 0 as everything else is working with that set 0 just obviously not pulling the rest of the data through.

Comment: is `item` the index of the question?

Comment: Yes thats basically what I would like, for each iteration create a number 0,1,2,3 that could slot in item to be used there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way I'm understanding the reading you need to get an indexed value from the original v-for to pass into the second.

try something like this

```
  <div v-for="(question, item) in questions.questions">
    {{question.question}}
    <div v-if="grouped_answers">
      <div v-for="a in grouped_answers[item].answers">
        {{a.id}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The second parameter in the v-for is the index/key passed by the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to do the following (pseudo code as I'm not sure where item is coming from):

```
<div v-for="question in questions.questions">
   {{question.question}}
    <div v-if="grouped_answers">
      <div v-for="a in grouped_answers[item].answers">
        {{a.id}}
      </div>
    </div>
   <div v-text="incrementItem(item)"></div>
</div>
```

---

**In Methods Block**

```
methods: {
  ...
  incrementItem: function(item) {return item + 1}
}
```

Basically something like this where you're calling to a method in your component to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I does add 1 once but doesnt update the key in the second loop or continue to add one for each of the first loops. How would I do that?

Comment: Could I just get the key of the first loop each time?

Answer (score 0):

try to add index

```
<div v-for="question in questions.questions">
   {{question.question}}
    <div v-if="grouped_answers">
  <div v-for="a in grouped_answers[item].answers">
    {{a.id}}
  </div>
</div>
   <div v-text="item.index"></div>
 </div>
```

if you can get index of element you dont need to write incrementor method,
but if you want, do like this:
...
data:{
number:0
}
....

```
methods: {

 incrementItem: function() {
    number +=1
    return number
}
}
```